# Log4J2 - RollingFile Appender keeps on rolling

Tags: java, log4j2

I am developing a little REST Service which logs it's informations to a monthly rolling logfile. At least it should. But once the timebased rolling trigger kicks in, every logstatement that follows creates a new logroll.

Here's my config file:

```
{
  "configuration": {
  "name": "Default",
  "properties": {
     "property": {
        "name":"FileName",
        "value":"restService.log"
     }
  },
  "appenders": {
     "Console": {
        "name":"stdout",
        "PatternLayout": {
           "pattern":"%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %m%n"
        }
     },
     "RollingFile": {
        "name":"File",
        "fileName":"./${FileName}",
        "filePattern":"./${date:yyyy-MM}/restService-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz",
        "PatternLayout": {
           "pattern":"%d %p %logger{36}.%M():%L [%t ThreadId:%T]: %m%n"
        },
        "Policies": {
           "CronTriggeringPolicy": {
              "schedule":"0 0 0 1 * ?"
           }
        }
     }
  },
  "loggers": {
     "root": {
        "level":"info",
        "appender-ref": {
          "ref":"File"
        }
     }
  }
 }
}
```

This creates a subdirectory every month where there should be exactly one logfile for the last month.

E.g. if the month changes from 2016/12 to 2017/01 there is a directory called "2017-01" with the rolled logfile named "restService-2017-01-01-1.log.gz" which was copied from the file restService.log in the directory one level higher.

That works as it should ,but if the service logs a new message to its logfile it creates a new archived logfile in the subdirectory "2017-01" and names it "restService-2017-01-01-2.log.gz" and the basic logfile which should contain everything which was logged this ongoing month stays empty.
 
This happens with every log message after the trigger fired and with a default rolling max of 7, the whole log from last month would be deleted after 7 new log messages.

Does somebody know, what i am doing wrong or can point me in some direction?

Thank you in advance.
ubreckner

Comment: The CronTriggeringPolicy had quite a few bugs which should be fixed in the latest code and will be in the next release when it is cut.

Comment: Since i get the log4j2 from the Spring Boot starter parent, i am still using version 2.6.2. And you say in 2.7 the major problems (and this one too) is going to be fixed? Or in a later update?

Comment: Seems even 2.7 has some problems left: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1640

Comment: Oh i see, the fix seems pretty recent, too. I guess i'll have to wait for a version update. Thanks for pointing me to that issue.